# Blog engine suggestion on IIS7 for multiple domains?

Tags: iis-7, domain

I have a webserver on IIS7. It hosts multiple websites via host header redirects. I want to install one installation of some blog engine, such that I can host one or more blogs per domain. For example, www.foo.com/blog1, www.foo.com/blog2, www.bar.com/blog1, blog.foo.com, etc.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for what used to be called [WordPress MU](http://mu.wordpress.org/), and it now WordPress MultiSite which is now just a part of the normal WordPress isntall..  There is a help doc available for setting up a [multi-site system](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network).

Comment: As I understand it, WPMU would require installation of Apache and PHP, correct? I'm hoping for an analogue with less dependencies.

Comment: WordPress can run on IIS, or any other web server which supports PHP.  PHP would need to be installed though.  It also needs a MySQL database somewhere (SQL Server can be used with an extra download from Microsoft).  That's a total of 2 extra dependencies.  Just about anything will need a database, and an ASP.NET app has a dependency on the correct version of .NET being installed so it would have the same number of dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

[Movable Type](http://www.movabletype.org/) might also be an option. It also has the advantage on generating static pages, so the load on the server will be generally lighter, and it's very easy to scale out.